# Pattern matching on the last element of a List

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

we use `(x:xs)` to pattern match on the first element as in this example :

```
head' :: [a] -> a  
head' xs = case xs of [] -> error "No head for empty lists!"  
                      (x:_) -> x
```

is there a way to pattern match on the last element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GHC 6.10 or newer, use a [view pattern](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns).

> View patterns permit calling the view function inside the pattern and
>   matching against the result:
>
> ```hs
> size (view -> Unit) = 1
> size (view -> Arrow t1 t2) = size t1 + size t2
> ```
>
> That is, we add a new form of pattern, written
>
> ```
> expression -> pattern
> ```
>
> that means “apply the expression to whatever we're trying to match
>   against, and then match the result of that application against the
>   pattern.” The expression can be any Haskell expression of function
>   type, and view patterns can be used wherever patterns are currently
>   used.

Define `head'` as

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

head' :: [a] -> a
head' (last -> l) = l
```

It works as you expect.

```hs
λ> head' [3,5,7]
7
λ> head' []
*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list
```

Answer (score 6):

No, because there is no constructor of type `[a] -> a -> [a]` to match.

You can use `[]` and `:` for pattern matching because they are, by definition, the building blocks of a list value. `[]` is *the* way to create an empty list. `:` is *the* way to build a new list from an element and another list. Functions like `append` do not create new lists by themselves; they *return* lists created by `:` and/or `[]`.

---

The exception is if you happen to know the length of the list in advance, in which case you can match the last element by matching *all* of the elements explicitly.

```
lastOfFour :: [a] -> a
lastOfFour (_:_:_:x:[]) = x
lastOfFour (_:_:_:_:_) = error "Too many elements"
lastOfFour _ = error "Too few elements"
```

The first error message is triggered if you can match at least 4 elements, and the remaining list is *not* empty; the second by any list that isn't matched by one of the first two.

Answer (score 5):

To get the the last element of list you need to traverse entire list.
If you need to match on the last element you probably need a list-like data structure which makes such match efficient and easy to use, like [Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Sequence.html) (where it is O(1) from both ends):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

import Data.Sequence

last' :: Seq a -> a
last' Empty = error "Empty sequence"
last' (_:|>a) = a

test = last' [1..5]
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning explicitly that `:|>` is actually a *pattern synonym* rather than a data constructor. But it's a reasonable pattern synonym because the underlying operations (`viewr` and `|>`) are O(1) (amortized, but validly so even for persistent use). Basically, `:|>` and its twin `:<|` are just a constant factor slower than real constructors.

Answer (score 3):

In GHC, you can define a [pattern synonym](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-synonyms) for this, if you really want to.  It will still be *O*(*n*), of course.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}

unsnoc :: [a] -> Maybe ([a], a)
unsnoc [] = Nothing
unsnoc xs = Just (init xs, last xs)

{-# COMPLETE [], (:>) #-}
infixl 5 :>
pattern (:>) :: [a] -> a -> [a]
pattern xs :> x <- (unsnoc -> Just (xs, x))
  where xs :> x = xs ++ [x]

-- example:

last' :: [a] -> a
last' [] = error "last': empty list"
last' (_ :> x) = x
```

(`unsnoc` is also in [`Data.List.Extra`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6.14/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:unsnoc).)

Comment: I'm personally wary of pattern synonyms for operations that are worse than polylogarithmic or so. There's no technical problem with such patterns, but they're likely to break users' intuition about performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t match on the last element directly, since pattern matching only deconstructs things based on the concrete constructors of the type, and lists only have two constructors: `[]` and `(:)`.

However, you can reverse the list, then match on the head of the reversed list:

```
last' xs = case reverse xs of
  [] -> error "last' []"
  x : _ -> x
```

With `ViewPatterns` you can do that reversal directly in the pattern:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

last' (reverse -> xs) = case xs of
  [] -> error "last' []"
  x : _ -> x
```

Or with `PatternGuards` you can do the reversal in a guard:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternGuards #-}

last' xs
  | x : _ <- reverse xs = x
  | otherwise = error "last' []"
```

Finally, with `PatternSynonyms` you can package this up with a name:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

pattern Reversed xs x <- (reverse -> x : xs)

  -- This part is optional, but allows writing:
  --
  --   Reversed [3, 2, 1] 0
  --
  -- As a synonym for:
  --
  --   [0, 1, 2, 3]
  --
  where Reversed xs x = x : reverse xs

last' (Reversed _ x) = x
last' _ = error "last' []"
```

All of these solutions are O(*n*) (linear) in the length of the list, which is unavoidable. So you might be better off making the traversal as explicit as possible, instead of hiding the linear cost and inadvertently traversing the list more than you intended, or using a different data structure with O(1) (constant) indexing of the last element, such as a `Seq` or `Vector`.

Answer (score -2):

As chepner pointed out, there is no built-in way to do this, but it's also not hard to write your own:

```
foo :: [Maybe a] -> a
foo [] = error "empty list"
foo xs =
  case last xs
    (Just a) -> a
    Nothing -> error "last element is a Nothing!"
```

Another way would be to `reverse` the list, and then pattern match on the first element!

Comment: This answer is a bit puzzling to me. Why have you specialized to `Maybe`s? Why is `foo` a better building-block than `last` itself?

Comment: I suppose I answered the question's title, when perhaps all the OP wants is `last` itself? `Maybe` is just an example type to pattern-match on.

Comment: This isn't pattern matching on the list; it's pattern matching on the return value of `last`.